# Map refresh on button click-Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

JS:

```
function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng({{location_latitude}}, {{location_longitude}});
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
```

Map is loading at the time of page load.

Apart from that,i need it to refresh the map on a button click,namely `"<button>Refresh Map</button>"`

How to make the map refresh on clicking `Refresh Map` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('button').on('click',initialize);
```